# How to include local JS files in Meteor App?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm fairly new to meteor. And I am having a terrible time understanding how to include local .js files into my Meteor App.

I'm referring to files which are usually included using  tags.

However I cannot find any good documentation regarding this. I wish to import some bootstrap files.

Pardon my novice experience. But require immediate help with this.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

you can use `import` syntax to import external js file

Ex.

```
import task from '../imports/api/tasks.js';
```

here ../imports/api/ is path to file.

you must export your functionality in external file

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use them, then go for import.

If you need only to import them, for instance if they are dependencies, you just have to put the scripts in the /lib or client/lib and they will be automatically imported.

See https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html